# Parsing json from webhook

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, quickbooks-online

I'm attempting to set up a webhook with Quickbooks and for testing I'm using a sample of the JSON they will post to the webhook.

**The format of the JSON is as follows:**

```
{
    "eventNotifications":[
    {
        "realmId":"1185883450",
        "dataChangeEvent":
        {
            "entities":[
            {
                "name":"Customer",
                "id":"1",
                "operation":"Create",
                "lastUpdated":"2015-10-05T14:42:19-0700"
            },
            {
                "name":"Vendor",
                "id":"1",
                "operation":"Create",
                "lastUpdated":"2015-10-05T14:42:19-0700"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Using Javascript, I attempted to parse it a couple ways but I keep getting stuck on the entities part.

**Attempt 1:**
With this attempt, I get an error that length is undefined, which led me to try the next attempt.

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.eventNotifications.length; i++) {

    // Works fine
    realmId.push(req.body.eventNotifications[i].realmId);

    for (var j = 0; j < req.body.eventNotifications[i].dataChangeEvent.entities.length; j++) {
        // length is undefined
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2:**
I don't get the error as above but anything I try to access underneath entities is undefined.

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.eventNotifications.length; i++) {

    // Works fine
    realmId.push(req.body.eventNotifications[i].realmId);

    for (var j = 0; j < req.body.eventNotifications[i].dataChangeEvent.length; j++) {
        // Anything I try to access is undefined
        var test = req.body.eventNotifications[i].dataChangeEvent[j].entities.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.eventNotifications.length; i++) {

    // Works fine
    realmId.push(req.body.eventNotifications[i].realmId);

    var eventNotification = req.body.eventNotifications[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < eventNotification.dataChangeEvent.entities.length; j++) {
        var entityName = eventNotification.dataChangeEvent.entities[j].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you please provide a brief explanation as to why/how it works?

Comment: The first loop iterates over the `eventNotifications` array, for readability I stored each `eventNotifications` object to be used in the second loop in  a variable `eventNotification`. The second loop iterates over the `entitities` array, you can access directly to it since `dataChangeEvent` is an object: `eventNotification.dataChangeEvent.entities`. Hope it helps :)